# Magento - Finding simple products with no configurable products

Tags: magento

recently I ran in to a problem that has been driving me spare, within Magento, a system where you have 4.5k simple products, how do you find the ones that are not assigned to configurable groups? Has anyone else run in to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM catalog_product_entity where entity_id not in ( select product_id from catalog_product_super_link )
AND type_id = 'simple'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using magento Model

```
$simple_products = $model->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE);
foreach($simple_products as $simpleProduct) {
    $parentIds = '';
    $parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProduct->getId());
    if(!$parentIds) {
        echo $simpleProduct->getId();
    }
}
```

It will print all simple products which is not associated with any configurable product. 
Hope this will help!